# Connection is not opening when I want to fetch data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sqlconnection

Connection is not opening  when I want to fetch data from database in the same window. Exception said "time expires".

The code is below...

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; initial catalog=xyz; user id=sa; password=charcha;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from catagories where Id=1", con);

        con.Open();
        using (con)
        {
            SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (DR.Read())
            {

                int Id = Convert.ToInt16(DR["Id"]);
                MainWindow MW = new MainWindow();
                //this.TBlock
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(DR["Name"]));
                w1TB.Text = Name;
                con.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is exception message?

Comment: Are you able to connect the db ok using SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

put "con.Open();"  inside the tag "using (con)"

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; initial catalog=xyz; user id=sa; password=charcha;"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from catagories where Id=1", con);

        con.Open();
        ...etc...
    }
```